# How to exit KDE connect

Tags: applications

As simple as the title states - How to exit/kill the [KDE connect app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kde.kdeconnect_tp) when I don't use it. Even if I kill the app from task manager (not sure if it is the correct term) I still see the notification in the notification bar which I assume means the app is still running in the background.

I found answers on how to turn off the notification, but I don't want to do that.
I want the notification visible when the app is running.

Comment: The app uses a small background service that is active independently of the GUI. Depending on the Android version you can enable the "Background Restriction" (disallow running the app in background) in the app's settings (not the one inside the app, but the one provided by Android settings).